# How to reset mload after job?

Tags: bash, teradata, mload

I am running an mload script on a table that is cleared at the beginning of a job. When the script fails, the error and log tables prevent the job from running a second time. How does one reset mload cleanly after a failure?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to drop the work/error/log table

- `DROP TABLE UV_mytable;`
- `DROP TABLE ET_mytable;`
- `DROP TABLE WT_mytable;`
- `DROP TABLE LT_mytable;`

And then release the load lock:

- `RELEASE MLOAD mytable;`,

If this fails

- `RELEASE MLOAD mytable IN APPLY;`

But why does the job fail at all?

Comment: Not to mention a release of a MutliLoad in application phase invalidates the table being loaded, meaning the table may have to be restored or recreated.